# Hiding LWC datatable Header

Tags: lightning-web-components

My Coloum header are still getting displayed even if there is no data in datatable. I want to hide it in case it doesnt contain any data. I have contained my Datatable in template. but still the column header are getting displayed! Any solutions?

```
<template>
    <p id="custom" class="slds-box slds-text-heading_small" style="background-color:WhiteSmoke;">
        <lightning-icon icon-name="custom:custom11"></lightning-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b style="font-size:14px">Selected EGs&nbsp;({count})</b>&nbsp;
     
    </p>
    
    <template if:true={showPPGRecords}>
  <div>
    <lightning-datatable key-field="Id" 
    data={priclst}  
    columns={columns}  
    hide-checkbox-column="true"  
    show-row-number-column="false"  
    >  
</lightning-datatable> 
 </div>
</template>
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement,api,wire } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import getSelectedEGs from '@salesforce/apex/PricingRequestGenericController.getPPGEGRelatedList';

const FIELDS = ['Account.Relationship_Status__c'];
const columns = [ 
    { label: 'Title', fieldName: 'Title__c' },
    { label: 'Entitlement Id', fieldName: 'EG_Number__c' },
    { label: 'Number', fieldName: 'Bse_c' },
    { label: 'Related Party', fieldName: 'MA3__c' }    ,  
    { label: 'Center', fieldName: 'Center__c' },

];


export default class RelatedEGForProductPricingGroup extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
    isNewVisible = true;
    Account;
    currenObjectName;
    error;
    columns = columns;
    priclst=[];
    callChildCmp;
    currenRecordId;
    showPPGRecords=false;
    hideHeader = false;
    count='';
    
 
    //End Code
    connectedCallback() {
        this.currenRecordId = this.recordId;
        this.currenObjectName = this.objectApiName;
        getSelectedEGs( { currentRecordId:this.recordId} )    
        .then(result => {  
            if(result)
            {
            this.showPPGRecords = true;   
            this.priclst=result;
            this.count = result.length;  
            }
            else{
                this.count = 0;
            }
        })  
        .catch(error => {  
             this.error = error;    
        }); 
          
    }
  
    handleView()
    {
        var compDetails = {
            componentDef: "c:relatedlstNavPricingApproval",
            attributes: {
                 //passing reordId to the next lwc component
                getIdFromParent: this.recordId,
                getObjectApi:this.currenObjectName
               
            }
        };
        var encodedCompDetails = btoa(JSON.stringify(compDetails));
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__webPage',
            attributes: {
                url: '/one/one.app#' + encodedCompDetails
            }
        });
    }
    handleNew()
    {
        

         this.callPricingApproval=true;        
    }
    handleNewPricingRequest(){
        this.callPricingGenericCMP=true;        
    }
 }
```

Comment: What you have in if:true={}? Please post the relevant code in your question

Answer (score 0):

**Update :**

length of result variable could be zero hence check length of result for assigning value to showPPGRecords

```
//End Code
    connectedCallback() {
        this.currenRecordId = this.recordId;
        this.currenObjectName = this.objectApiName;
        getSelectedEGs( { currentRecordId:this.recordId} )    
        .then(result => {  
            if(result)
            {
            this.showPPGRecords = !!result.length;   
            this.priclst=result;
            this.count = result.length;  
            }
            else{
                this.count = 0;
            }
        })  
        .catch(error => {  
             this.error = error;    
        }); 
          
    }
```

Comment: I was doing this but it is not hiding the Datatable column header for me. Is it working for you?

Comment: It is working for me. If you will post your code will be able to help you.

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: this.showPPGRecords = true; Replace this with  this.showPPGRecords = !!result.length;

even if result length is 0  showPPGRecords will be set to true

Comment: I have updated the code. notice  this.showPPGRecords = !!result.length;

Comment: How the length operator will work on something which is null!

Comment: If result is undefined or null then if(result) it will not pass and showPPGRecords will remain false and table won't render. if result is initialized blank i.e result = [] then length operator will work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have any standard tag to hide the column headers as they are used to map your data items in the order. You'll probably need to go for custom CSS to hide the column headers.

EDITED :

I am unaware of any styling hook. However, you can go with the below option -

1. Create a static resource for CSS. e.g dtStyle.css
   Enclose your datable in a custom class -

```html
<div class="myTable">
    <lightning-datatable
        key-field="Id"
        data={tableData}
        columns={columns}
        hide-checkbox-column>
    </lightning-datatable>
</div>
```

2. 

```css
.myTable table>thead {
  display:none;
}
```

3. Import the CSS in your LWC Component

```js
import {loadStyle} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader'
import DTSTYLE from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/dtStyle'
```

4. In the rendered callback of LWC -

```js
renderedCallback(){ 
    loadStyle(this, DTSTYLE).then(()=>{
        console.log("Loaded Successfully")
    }).catch(error=>{ 
        console.error("Error in loading the colors")
    })
}
```

Comment: Also If there is any styling hook for this?